# How to delay script tag until other script tag has run

Tags: javascript, html, metaprogramming, script-tag

I've been experimenting with metaprogramming in webpages, and need to delay a script tag from running until *just* after another script tag has been run. However, the script tag needs to be loaded first or both of them will fail.

Shortened and more readable version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<script defer>
    w=function(){
        <stuff that gives a parser error until modified by the next script tag>
    }
</script>
<script>
    <stuff that changes the previous script tag and any other script tags that ever will be added via the DOM
    so it doesn't give a parser error>
</script>
<button onclick='w()'></button>
```

This would work perfectly well, except that the button's `onclick` attribute fails because the button was loaded before the first script tag was run.
Thanks in advance!

(EDIT: [I linked a pastebin to show the full version of my code, it might clear things up a bit since it seems my summed-up version wasn't very good.](https://pastebin.com/xtRUUGCH)

Comment: so why don't you have the one trigger a message or call the other when it is supposed to run?

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't both have the script tag in the DOM with its content accessible to your second script tag, and somehow prevent it from being parsed. You probably want to do some kind of dynamic code generation entirely in one script tag and then `eval` the result.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure how to use messages, maybe that's the way to go. I can't call the other one either, because that would result in both of them having the parser error.
@meagar I can edit the script tag before it's parsed using `defer`.

Comment: Are you just trying to feed the contents of the first script tag into the second, as input? If so, make the first tag a `<script type="text/x-template">` and you can put anything you like inside it. Then read its content with your second script tag, transform it into valid JavaScript, and `eval` it.

Comment: Makes no sense why they are dependent on each other.... seems like if they require each other than deferring is wrong....

Comment: The deferring one is dependent on the other in order to be syntactically viable. The one that uses DOM is dependent because otherwise it will be targeting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @meagar in the comments, if you don't mind changing the `type` property of your "not actually javascript" script blocks you can do something like this:

```html
<script type='derpscript'>
  var derp;
  var w=function(){alert('hello')}; 
  derp||=5;
  console.log(derp);
</script>

<script>
function compileDerps() {
  // find all derpscript script tags
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('script[type=derpscript]');
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    meta=x[i].text
    while(true){
      pastmeta=meta;
      console.log(exc=regex.exec(meta))
      if(exc){
        meta=meta.replace(regex,exc[1]+'='+exc[1]+'||');
      }
      if(pastmeta==meta){break;}
    }
    // make a new javascript script tag to hold the compiled derp
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.text = meta;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    // delete the derpscript tag
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
  }
}

    //stuff that changes the previous script tag and any other script tags that ever will be added via the DOM
    var regex=/([a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_1-9]*)(\|\|\=)/;
    var meta;
    var pastmeta='';
    var exc='';

    compileDerps();
</script>

<button onclick='w()'>THIS IS W</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really useful to me! I especially like how you named it `derpscript`, I think that's a fun name.